# Hide rows from Datatables based on a value of a column using laravel , Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a datatable, and I want when I click on a button Hide, go to Database and get the value of status column and hide from the datatable all rows with status column equal to 0.

I tried the following code but doesn't work for me.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

$("#hide").click(function() {
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
      function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
          return $(table.row(dataIndex).node()).attr('status') == 1;
        }
    );
    table.draw();
});    
$("#reset").click(function() {
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop();
    table.draw();
});
```

```js
var data = [{
    "id": "1",
    "status": 1,
    "name": "Tiger Nixon",
    "position": "System Architect",
    "salary": "$320,800",
    "start_date": "2011/04/25",
    "office": "Edinburgh",
    "extn": "5421"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "status": 0,
    "name": "Garrett Winters",
    "position": "Accountant",
    "salary": "$170,750",
    "start_date": "2011/07/25",
    "office": "Tokyo",
    "extn": "8422"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "status": 1,
    "name": "Ashton Cox",
    "position": "Junior Technical Author",
    "salary": "$86,000",
    "start_date": "2009/01/12",
    "office": "San Francisco",
    "extn": "1562"
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "status": 1,
    "name": "Cedric Kelly",
    "position": "Senior Javascript Developer",
    "salary": "$433,060",
    "start_date": "2012/03/29",
    "office": "Edinburgh",
    "extn": "6224"
  },
  {
    "id": "5",
    "active": 0,
    "name": "Airi Satou",
    "position": "Accountant",
    "salary": "$162,700",
    "start_date": "2008/11/28",
    "office": "Tokyo",
    "extn": "5407"
  },
];

$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    data: data,
    rowId: 'id',
    columns: [{
        targets: 0,
        data: "status",
        render: function(data, type, row) {
          if (type === 'display') {
            return '<input type="checkbox"  class="editor-active">';
          }
          return data;
        },
        className: "dt-body-center"
      },
      {
        "data": "name"
      },
      {
        "data": "position"
      },
      {
        "data": "office"
      },
      {
        "data": "extn"
      },
      {
        "data": "start_date"
      },
      {
        "data": "salary"
      }
    ],

    pageLength: 2,

    order: [
      [1, 'asc']
    ],

    rowCallback: function(row, data) {
      $('input.editor-active', row).prop('checked', data.status== 1).bootstrapToggle({
        size: 'mini'
      });
    }

  });

  $('#example').on('change', 'input.editor-active', function() {
    console.log(table.row($(this).closest('tr')).id());

  });

});

$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#hide").click(function() {
    
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  font: 90%/1.45em "Helvetica Neue", HelveticaNeue, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs-3.3.7/dt-1.10.16/datatables.min.css" />

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs-3.3.7/dt-1.10.16/datatables.min.js"></script>

  <link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>

  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">

    <button id="hide">hide data-status=0</button>
    <button id="reset">reset</button>
    <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Checkbox</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Start date</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th>Checkbox</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Start date</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>

    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

When for example I switch the checkbox to OFF , the status column in dtatatable change to 0 , Now I want when I click on button `hide data-status=0` hide from datatable all rows with checkbox with vvalue off (status in database equal to 0)

**Updated**

My table :

```
 <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 mb-4 data-table-rows data-tables-hide-filter">
                        <table id="datatableRows" class="data-table responsive nowrap"
                            data-order="[[ 1, &quot;desc&quot; ]]">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Image</th>
                                    <th>Nom</th>
                                    <th>CIN</th>
                                    <th>Phone</th>
                                   
                                   <th>Action</th> 
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Function witch get Data from Database :

```
function getdata(Request $request)
{
    if(request()->ajax())
    {
        return datatables()->of(Casting::latest()->get())
            ->addColumn('action', function($data){
                $button = '<table><tr><td>';
                $button .= '<button type="button" name="edit" id="'.$data->id.'" class="edit btn btn-primary btn-sm">Modifier</button>';
                $button .= '</td><td>';
                $button .= ' <label  class="switch" >';
                $button .= '  <input type="checkbox" id="'.$data->id.'" class="switch selectRow" ';
                
                if ($data->status == 1) {

                    $button .= "checked";
                }

                $button .= '><span class="slider round"></span></label>';
                $button .= '</td></tr></table>';

                return $button;
        })
        ->rawColumns(['action'])
        ->make(true);
    }
    return view('Casting.castingss');
}
```

Function which updates the status value :

```
  public function changeStatus(Request $request)
    {
       $request->validate(['status'=>'required','id'=>'required']);
        $casting = Casting::find($request->id);
        if($casting){
        $casting->status = $request->status;
        $casting->save();
       return response()->json(['success'=>'Status change successfully.']);
        }
       return response()->json(['failed'=>'Status change failed.'],422);
           
        }

And My script : 

 $('#datatableRows').DataTable({

  processing: true,
  serverSide: true,
  ajax:{
   url: "{{ route('castingss.getdata') }}",
  },
  columns:[
  
   {
    data: 'casting_photo',
    name: 'casting_photo',
    render: function(data, type, full, meta){

              return "<img src={{ URL::to('/') }}/castingimages/" + data +  " class='list-thumbnail responsive border-0 card-img-left' />";
    },
    orderable: false
   },
   {data:'casting_name',
    name: 'casting_name',
    render:function(data,type,full,meta){
      return "<a href='profile'>" + data + "</a>";
    }
   },
    {
    data: 'casting_cin',
    name: 'casting_cin'
   },
   {
   data:   "casting_phone",
   name:   "casting_phone"
   },
   
   {
    data: 'action',
    name: 'action',
    orderable: false
   }
  ] 
 });



$(document).on('change', '.selectRow', function(){

        var status = $(this).prop('checked') == true ? 1 : 0; 

          var id = $(this).attr('id');

            $.ajax({

            type: "get",

            dataType: "json",

            url: '/changeStatus',

            data: {'status': status, 'id': id},

            success: function(data){

              console.log(data.success)

            }

        });


    });
```

**UPDATED2**

```
$('#datatableRows').DataTable({

  processing: true,
  serverSide: true,
  ajax:{
   url: "{{ route('castingss.getdata') }}",
  },
  columns:[
  
   {
    data: 'casting_photo',
    name: 'casting_photo',
    render: function(data, type, full, meta){

              return "<img src={{ URL::to('/') }}/castingimages/" + data +  " class='list-thumbnail responsive border-0 card-img-left' />";
    },
    orderable: false
   },
   {data:'casting_name',
    name: 'casting_name',
    render:function(data,type,full,meta){
      return "<a href='profile'>" + data + "</a>";
    }
   },
    {
    data: 'casting_cin',
    name: 'casting_cin'
   },
   {
   data:   "casting_phone",
   name:   "casting_phone"
   },
   
   {
    data: 'action',
    name: 'action',
    orderable: false
   }
  ] 
 });



$(document).on('change', '.selectRow', function(){

        var status = $(this).prop('checked') == true ? 1 : 0; 

          var id = $(this).attr('id');

            $.ajax({

            type: "get",

            dataType: "json",

            url: '/changeStatus',

            data: {'status': status, 'id': id},

            success: function(data){

              console.log(data.success)

            }

        });


    });



$("#hide").click(function() {

  alert('je suis là');

    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
      function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
          return $(table.row(dataIndex).node()).find('.selectRow').prop("checked") == true;
        }
    );
    table.draw();
});
$("#reset").click(function() {
  $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop();
  table.draw();
});
```

But nothing occurs

Comment: Not clear why you would be searching for an element attribute and not row data. As for going to the database you would need to use ajax to load more data. Are you rendering html rows server side currently? A [mre] would be helpful

Comment: @charlietfl please check my edit

Answer (score 1):

You can use `table.row(dataIndex).data().status` to get status value and if its `1` show them else hide . Also, user can check/uncheck your checkboxes so you need to update your status value to `1` or `0` so that next time when you click on `reset` button it will update rows accordingly else it will hide checked rows as well.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var data = [{
    "id": "1",
    "status": 1,
    "name": "Tiger Nixon",
    "position": "System Architect",
    "salary": "$320,800",
    "start_date": "2011/04/25",
    "office": "Edinburgh",
    "extn": "5421"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "status": 0,
    "name": "Garrett Winters",
    "position": "Accountant",
    "salary": "$170,750",
    "start_date": "2011/07/25",
    "office": "Tokyo",
    "extn": "8422"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "status": 1,
    "name": "Ashton Cox",
    "position": "Junior Technical Author",
    "salary": "$86,000",
    "start_date": "2009/01/12",
    "office": "San Francisco",
    "extn": "1562"
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "status": 1,
    "name": "Cedric Kelly",
    "position": "Senior Javascript Developer",
    "salary": "$433,060",
    "start_date": "2012/03/29",
    "office": "Edinburgh",
    "extn": "6224"
  },
  {
    "id": "5",
    "status": 0,
    "name": "Airi Satou",
    "position": "Accountant",
    "salary": "$162,700",
    "start_date": "2008/11/28",
    "office": "Tokyo",
    "extn": "5407"
  },
];


var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  data: data,
  rowId: 'id',
  columns: [{
      targets: 0,
      data: "status",
      render: function(data, type, row) {
        if (type === 'display') {
          return '<input type="checkbox"  data-toggle="toggle" class="editor-active">';
        }
        return data;
      },
      className: "dt-body-center"
    },
    {
      "data": "name"
    },
    {
      "data": "position"
    },
    {
      "data": "office"
    },
    {
      "data": "extn"
    },
    {
      "data": "start_date"
    },
    {
      "data": "salary"
    }
  ],

  pageLength: 2,

  order: [
    [1, 'asc']
  ],

  rowCallback: function(row, data) {

    $('input.editor-active', row).prop('checked', data.status == 1).bootstrapToggle({
      size: 'mini'
    });
  }

});

$('#example').on('change', 'input.editor-active', function() {
  var datas = table.row($(this).closest('tr')).data(); //get data
  datas.status = $(this).is(":checked") ? 1 : 0; //update status..
  table.row($(this).closest('tr')).data(datas).draw(); //draw row again..
});



$("#hide").click(function() {
  $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
      //get status value..
      return table.row(dataIndex).data().status == 1
    }
  );
  table.draw();
});
$("#reset").click(function() {
  $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop();
  table.draw();
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs-3.3.7/dt-1.10.16/datatables.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs-3.3.7/dt-1.10.16/datatables.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">

  <button id="hide">hide data-status=0</button>
  <button id="reset">reset</button>
  <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Checkbox</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th>Checkbox</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>

  </table>
</div>
```

***Update 1*** :

You can simply check if the `selectRow` is checked or not depending on this show rows else hide them .So , jquery code will look like below :

```
$("#hide").click(function() {
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
      function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
          return $(table.row(dataIndex).node()).find('.selectRow').prop("checked") == true;
        }
    );
    table.draw();
});
$("#reset").click(function() {
  $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop();
  table.draw();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply , but in my case I have not the column status in my Table I have just a toggle switch custom whitch updates the status value in database

Comment: please check my Updaye , how can I hide the rows with status equal to 0

Comment: see my script , I tried ur updated code but doesn't work

Comment: Can you show output of `console.log($(table.row(dataIndex).node()).html())`  of only one node put that line inside `function(settings, data, dataIndex) {..`  just need to see where `selectRow` is located .

Comment: like that : $("#hide").click(function() {

  alert('je suis là');

    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
      function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
          console.log($(datatableRows.row(dataIndex).node()).html());
        }
    );
    table.draw();
});

Comment: it shows me : castingss:1026 Uncaught ReferenceError: table is not defined

Comment: Yes , you have not added `var table = $('#datatableRows').DataTable({...` save datatable reference in some variable.. like i have did in my previous answer . Then , you can use it anywhere in your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233439/discussion-between-swati-and-user14053977).